# Elementary os on login <ERROR> failed to enable link training

Tags: graphic-drivers, drivers, intel

When logging in the system knocks an error:

[drm: intel_dp_start_link_train [i915]] failed to enable link training

Maybe it happened because of whom I installed nvidia-smi. No video card, Intel-i7 processor.

[image: error screenshot]

Thank you in advance

Comment: You do have a graphics card. It's embedded on your Intel processor and uses the i915 driver. Anyway we need more info like kernel version, you can get it on terminal with `uname -r`. Also, did you install any driver package? How did you do it?